The Crown Laurel? British sci-fi film from the 70's maybe?
I've searched intermittently for decades for a show or film I saw when I was little in the 70's. I think it was British, but I'm not sure. The story is a man goes to a therapist because whatever he imagines becomes reality. The therapist doesn't believe him, of course, until he is able to hypnotize the patient and give him suggestions. It's a post-apocalyptic earth of extreme over-population and other problems, one of them being constant rain. The therapist suggests the 'patient' think of sunshine. The therapist runs up to the roof of his office building to see that the rains have indeed stopped, but now it's incessant sunshine. All the people are still quite crowded and now hot and sweaty all the time. The therapist keeps trying to "fix" the world's problems using the patient's abilities. The therapist actually wants the ability for himself. I don't remember exactly how it ended. If anyone has any info on this, or if it's attainable on a disc, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The Lathe of Heaven

This science-fiction drama, set in a near future world, focuses on a
  psychiatrist who realizes that one of his patients has the power to
  change reality through his dreams. The psychiatrist attempts to use
  the dreamer's power to create a utopian world, with unexpected and
  often negative results.




